# Remove Peanut Oil Stain from Carpet?

Tags: cleaning, carpet, stain

A can of peanut butter spilled some of its oil onto the carpet causing a dark stain. I scrubbed it immediately but it didn't come up. After Googling the problem, I tried putting baking soda on the stain, letting it set and scrubbing with dish soap, but that trick didn't work either.

It's now set into the carpet and seems to be with us permanently. Is there any way to remove a set in oil stain from carpeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was researching the solution provided by @computercarguy I came across a product that works even better: **Oxy Power Shot** - This stain had been set in for months and it took it right up like it wasn't even there. Here's what I did.

- Soak the stain for 5 minutes
- Scrub vigorously with a paper towel.
- Ran the robot vacuum over the spot repeatedly in Strong mode.

It worked.

Comment: Yaaaay! Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple articles doing a basic Search, but this one seems to be the easiest to read as well as incorporates the other ideas.

*Disclosure:* I have not tried this myself and I have no affiliation with the site linked below.

> ## Carpet
>
> What you will need
>
> - Dry Cleaning solvent
> - Detergent
> - White vinegar
>
> ## Steps to Clean
>
> - Scrape off excess foreign material.
> - Using an eye dropper, apply a small amount of acetone to the stains.  (Caution: Do not use acetone on fabrics containing acetate or triacetate.  It will melt the fibers!)
> - Blot immediately.
> - Using a clean white cloth, sponge the stain with the dry cleaning solvent.
> - Blot until the solvent is absorbed.
> - If the stain remains, mix one tablespoon of liquid dishwashing detergent and one tablespoon of white vinegar with two cups of warm water. Sponge the stain with this solution. Blot until the liquid is absorbed.
> - Sponge with cold water and blot dry to remove the detergent/vinegar solution.

https://web.extension.illinois.edu/stain/staindetail.cfm?ID=132